# Array equals 0 in numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a `UITableViewController` that I use to display the names of a list of local Business objects. I have used this `UITableViewController` 
previously to read information from a .csv file and this was all working and displaying the Business names in my `UITableViewController` perfectly.

However, I have recently moved all this information to Parse.com and I am now trying to read and display the information from Parse.com in my current `UITableViewController`.

I am trying to refactor the code rather than use Parse.com's tutorials here:
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-tables/iOS

In my `viewDidLoad` method, I call my own method `[self initializeContent]` which does the `PFQuery` to retrieve a list of objects that fit a certain criteria and then save the objects in an `NSMutableArray`.

This executes fine and I can see the Business objects are being retrieved through my `NSLogs` in my `[self initializeContent]` method and saved to a `NSMutableArray` (dataArray).
However, when stepping through the code, my `dataArray` is 0 in the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method. Therefore I dont see the Business names displayed in the `UITableViewController`.

Does the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` get executed before the `viewDidLoad` method perhaps, meaning that my `dataArray` will always be 0?

I have stepped through the code but cant figure out where my issue is.

Below is my code - I have included as much as I can to help identify where my problem is.

```
BusinessDetailTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface BusinessDetailTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *defaultBusinessArrayMutable;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int tagNumber;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *className;

@end
```

BusinessDetailTableViewController.m

```
#import "BusinessDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "BusinessDetailContent.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface BusinessDetailTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation BusinessDetailTableViewController

@synthesize dataArray;
@synthesize defaultBusinessArrayMutable;
@synthesize tagNumber;
@synthesize className;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initializeArrays];
    [self initializeContent];
}

- (void) initializeArrays
{
    dataArray                   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    defaultBusinessArrayMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void) initializeContent
{
    NSLog(@"Class Name: %@", className);  // Shows the correct className
    [self queryParse:className];
}

- (void) queryParse:(NSString *) className
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Successfully Retrieved %d Objects.", (int)objects.count);    // Shows how many objects are retrieved

             for (PFObject *object in objects)
             {
                 BusinessDetailContent *businessDetailContent = [[BusinessDetailContent alloc] init];        
                 businessDetailContent.no           = object[@"ID"];
                 businessDetailContent.companyName  = object[@"Company_Name"];
                 businessDetailContent.address      = object[@"Address"];
                 businessDetailContent.tel          = object[@"Tel"];
                 businessDetailContent.email        = object[@"Email"];
                 businessDetailContent.website      = object[@"Website"];
                 businessDetailContent.details      = object[@"Details"];
                 businessDetailContent.imageName    = object[@"Image_ID"];

                 // The information here is retrieved correctly  
                 NSLog(@"BUSINESS DETAIL CONTENT - ID: %@, Company Name: %@, Address: %@, Tel: %@, Email: %@, Website: %@, Details: %@, Image_Name: %@",
                           businessDetailContent.no, businessDetailContent.companyName, businessDetailContent.address, businessDetailContent.tel,
                           businessDetailContent.email, businessDetailContent.website, businessDetailContent.details,
                           businessDetailContent.imageName);


                 [defaultBusinessArrayMutable addObject:businessDetailContent];


                 NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tagNumber];

                 if (!([strFromInt isEqualToString:@"3"] || [strFromInt isEqualToString:@"10"]))
                     {
                         [dataArray addObject:defaultBusinessArrayMutable];
                         NSLog(@"Default Business Array Mutable Count: %i", (int)dataArray.count);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error retrieving objects: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         }
     }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@" cellForRowAtIndexPath ");      // This is not executed

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSLog(@"Cell Identifier: %@", CellIdentifier);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    NSArray *cellArray = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    BusinessDetailContent *businessDetailContent = [cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = businessDetailContent.companyName;
    NSLog(@"Cell Textlabel Text: %@", cell.textLabel.text);

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@" didSelectRowAtIndexPath ");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"businessDetailSegue" sender:self];
}



- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection returning: %d", (int)[dataArray count]);      
    return [dataArray count];              // dataArray = 0
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [dataArray objectAtIndex:section];

    return [array count];
}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"PrepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"businessDetailSegue"] && indexPath)
    {
        NSArray *selectedRowArray = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        BusinessDetailContent *selectedContent = [selectedRowArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        DetailViewController *detailController = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailController.businessDetailContent = selectedContent;
    }
}a
@end
```

**EDIT:** I have added [self.tableView reloadData]; to the end of my findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method as many have suggested and now I am getting to the numberOfSectionsInTableView method, but the dataArray is still 0. And it looks as though my code is executing twice as can be seen by the Console print?

For my dataArray in my queryParse method it returns 18 objects - but there should be only 9.
From the Console print Hotel Array Count starts at 2 and increments by 2 each time after that.

And my numberOfRowsInSection is now getting executed twice, but before the Parse.com query.

I am totally stuck with this.

[image]

Comment: Firstly change the type of queryParse() method as void, because it not returns any thing. And then reload your tableView on main thread, before closing if(!error) statement.

Comment: Hi Student. Thanks for the heads-up on the return type. It was void previously but just tried something else and forgot to reset to void. Looks like the issue is the reload as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hans Moolman, yes you are correct, You just need to call the reload method of table view after your parsing is done. i .e.

```
- (NSMutableArray *) queryParse:(NSString *) className
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Successfully Retrieved %d Objects.", (int)objects.count);    // Shows how many objects are retrieved

             for (PFObject *object in objects)
             {
                 BusinessDetailContent *businessDetailContent = [[BusinessDetailContent alloc] init];        
                 businessDetailContent.no           = object[@"ID"];
                 businessDetailContent.companyName  = object[@"Company_Name"];
                 businessDetailContent.address      = object[@"Address"];
                 businessDetailContent.tel          = object[@"Tel"];
                 businessDetailContent.email        = object[@"Email"];
                 businessDetailContent.website      = object[@"Website"];
                 businessDetailContent.details      = object[@"Details"];
                 businessDetailContent.imageName    = object[@"Image_ID"];

                 // The information here is retrieved correctly  
                 NSLog(@"BUSINESS DETAIL CONTENT - ID: %@, Company Name: %@, Address: %@, Tel: %@, Email: %@, Website: %@, Details: %@, Image_Name: %@",
                           businessDetailContent.no, businessDetailContent.companyName, businessDetailContent.address, businessDetailContent.tel,
                           businessDetailContent.email, businessDetailContent.website, businessDetailContent.details,
                           businessDetailContent.imageName);


                 [defaultBusinessArrayMutable addObject:businessDetailContent];


                 NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tagNumber];

                 if (!([strFromInt isEqualToString:@"3"] || [strFromInt isEqualToString:@"10"]))
                     {
                         [dataArray addObject:defaultBusinessArrayMutable];
                         NSLog(@"Default Business Array Mutable Count: %i", (int)dataArray.count);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error retrieving objects: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         }
     }];
// This line to be added
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

If still problems exists, do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi mAc. I tried the solution you suggested but it is still not working for me. See my EDIT section on the original question on what the issue is. I have also added additional information from the Console (NSLog) printout.

Comment: Thank-you @mAc. I stepped through the code last night but cant figure out why its executing the way it is. The only thing I am doind different than my previous .csv version is Im now reading from Parse to my array, rather than from a .csv. And adding tableview.reload is executing but not when you would expect it to? Im really lost with this.

Comment: Hans, First put debugger on these methods, initializeArray,  numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSectionsInTableView, viewDidLoad and tell me the sequence of their call. One more thing to do is use :- - (void) initializeArrays
{
    self.dataArray                   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.defaultBusinessArrayMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}  i.e. use self for Array's.

Comment: Hi @mAc
I used self.defaultBusinessArray as you suggested but this did not help. I also used the debugger and can send you the order of execution if you want. 

What I then did was place the [self.tableView reloadData]; method inside my - for (PFObject *object in objects) - method and now I am able to display the objects in the UITableView. The problem is now that all objects are written twice to the UITableView. When I placed the [self.tableView reloadData]; where it was suggested, my code never executed this line for some reason?

I guess Im one step closer to solving this.

Comment: Hans, if u can mail me your code, do it hiding all imp details, i will populate data n revert you back :)

Comment: Hi @mAc. I really appreciate the offer but I have managed to get the app working. Ill mark your question as the answer but Ill just note that I had to place the [self.tableView reloadData]; inside my findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method - rather than outside as you and everyone here had suggested. Dont know is this a bug or something I was not doing in the code. Also I fixed the issue where all objects were being returned twice. It was the was to do with the way I was adding objects to an array. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The call to parse.com returns data asynchronously, so the view will have finished loading and done its check for row count before the data is received. When the data is received you need to tell the table view to check the row count again and refresh - this is what you're missing.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and it should go in `queryParse:`, at the end of the completion block of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Ill try that tonight when I get back to my development machine. That could explain why it looks like the code execution jumps out of my qeuryParse method and into the numberOfRowsInSection method when I was stepping through he code last night? Could not figure out why this was.

Answer (score 1):

Hi first you set bool value default to false i mean viewdidload.
By parsing at didfinishloading function set bool to true

In numberofrowsinsection

```
if(!bool)

{

///just hide the tableview

}

else
{



[data count];
}
```